# IO: 0.8A meaning?

Tags: current, motor

I have found a motor which I want and it has "IO: 0.8A" in the specifications. Could someone please let me know what this means. Thanks.

Edit 1: I haven't bought it yet but the amazon page can be found here: https://www.amazon.co.uk/SODIAL-Performance-Brushless-Airplane-Fixed-wing/dp/B075XFKJQZ/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1510600030&sr=8-3&keywords=2216+brushless

Comment: Photo, please (of the motor and the specs plate, of course)

Comment: It's a "no-load current"

Comment: I can't imagine buying a motor from a company that also sells these... https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07793Z27D/ref=s9_acsd_hps_bw_c_x_5_w

Comment: Oh... I should probably have checked the seller. Thanks Trevor. I will probably find another company to buy from.

Comment: @Trevor Would you buy a pillow from a motors seller?

Comment: @EugeneSh. not in those colours LOL

Answer (score 1):

It's a "no-load current". Creds to Eugene Sh.

Comment: You can mark this as the correct answer even though you wrote it yourself.

Comment: I know but it tells me to wait 2 days. Maybe it's because I'm new?

Comment: @RudraMutalik Nope, not because you're new. It's a general rule. Just make sure to come back in 2 days to mark it as accepted =)